# Margin looks fine Firefox and Safari but is much wider in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, margin

Ive got an issue whereby I have an inline-block with a margin that displays correctly in Safari and Firefox..but in IE for some reason the margin is a lot larger, that is the width is much wider in IE.. In fact the whole page in IE is displayed as if the browser window is a lot larger.

My CSS looks like below:

```
.wpcontainer {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 80%;
 margin-left: 10%;
 margin-right: 10%;
 padding: 1%;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: are you using a CSS reset? That can help sometimes.

Comment: Which version(s) of IE are you having this issue with?

Comment: Take a look at [this short article](http://www.lancelhoff.com/margin-differences-internet-explorer-and-firefox/) tackling this very problem. Hopefully it'll help.

Comment: You should provide some markup. I don't understand what's the point to combine inline-block and such properties of width & margin. Doesn't make sense to me. Why don't you use a block instead?

Answer (score 0):

i think you should give the link or whole code so that I can check on my computer what the problem is. And there is an issue in your CSS that is `width 80% + margin 20% + padding 2% = 102%`, actually it should be like this

```css
.wpcontainer {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 78%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding: 1%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```